# jwplayer unable to pseudo stream a video loaded via http handler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, jwplayer, httphandler, jwplayer6

I managed to set up modh264 on IIS 7 working just fine, pseudo streaming is working great.
I can't get jwplayer pseudo streaming to work with a httphandler in-between.
I mean the video starts from the beginning whenever you click in a different position! 
if I remove the handler the pseudo streaming works as expected.
My problem here is to prevent people gaining direct access to my videos (I don't care if they save the video via browser cache).
I had to load via 10k bytes chunks since videos are big enough to get memory exception

here's my httphandler

```
public class DontStealMyMoviesHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// You will need to configure this handler in the web.config file of your 
    /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
    /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
    /// </summary>
    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
        // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        HttpRequest req = context.Request;
        string path = req.PhysicalPath;
        string extension = null;
        string contentType = null;
        string fileName = "";
        if (req.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            context.Response.Redirect("~/Home/");
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = "file.mp4";

            if (req.UrlReferrer.Host.Length > 0)
            {
                if (req.UrlReferrer.ToString().ToLower().Contains("/media/"))
                {
                    context.Response.Redirect("~/Home/");
                }
            }
        }

        extension = Path.GetExtension(req.PhysicalPath).ToLower();
        switch (extension)
        {
            case ".m4v":
            case ".mp4":
                contentType = "video/mp4";
                break;
            case ".avi":
                contentType = "video/x-msvideo";
                break;
            case ".mpeg":
                contentType = "video/mpeg";
                break;
            //default:
            //  throw new notsupportedexception("unrecognized video type.");
        }

        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            context.Response.Status = "movie not found";
            context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                //context.Response.Clear();
                //context.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=file.mp4");
                //context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
                //context.Response.WriteFile(path, false);

                //if(HttpRuntime.UsingIntegratedPipeline)
                //    context.Server.TransferRequest(context.Request.Url.ToString(), true);
                //else
                //    context.RewritePath(context.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.ToString(), true);


                // Buffer to read 10K bytes in chunk:
                byte[] buffer = new Byte[10000];
                // Length of the file:
                int length;
                // Total bytes to read:
                long dataToRead;
                using (FileStream iStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    // Total bytes to read:
                    dataToRead = iStream.Length;

                    context.Response.Clear();
                    context.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
                    context.Response.Cache.SetLastModified(DateTime.Now);
                    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", contentType);
                    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                    // Read the bytes.
                    while (dataToRead > 0)
                    {
                        // Verify that the client is connected.
                        if (context.Response.IsClientConnected)
                        {
                            // Read the data in buffer.
                            length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);

                            // Write the data to the current output stream.
                            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);

                            // Flush the data to the HTML output.
                            context.Response.Flush();

                            buffer = new Byte[10000];
                            dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //prevent infinite loop if user disconnects
                            dataToRead = -1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                context.Response.Redirect("home");
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: At the moment I can't since it's hosted in our intranet. We don't have a link who can be browsed externally. I can link in the coming hours an external link... I hope ;)

Comment: Ok, please let me know when a link is up, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved creating a httpmodule instead, Because with a httpHandler I had to manage the response myself causing the pseudo stream to fail (the file was loaded entirely to the output stream). While this way if someone is accessing the file directly I just do a simple redirect. I don't get why redirect to "~/" doesn't work.

```
public class DontStealMyMoviesModule : IHttpModule
{
    public DontStealMyMoviesModule()
    {
    }
    public void Init(HttpApplication r_objApplication)
    {
        // Register our event handler with Application object.
        r_objApplication.PreSendRequestContent +=new EventHandler(this.AuthorizeContent);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }

    private void AuthorizeContent(object r_objSender, EventArgs r_objEventArgs)
    {
        HttpApplication objApp = (HttpApplication)r_objSender;
        HttpContext objContext = (HttpContext)objApp.Context;

        HttpRequest req = objContext.Request;

        if (Path.GetExtension(req.PhysicalPath).ToLower() != ".mp4") return;

        if (req.UrlReferrer == null)
        {
            objContext.Response.Redirect("/");
        }
    }
}
```